# I'm trying to call a row from an HTML table into a JS function

Tags: javascript, html

I started last night so i'm a) sure there is an easy solution and b) not oblivious to the fact that my code is very crappy. 
So i pulled this Stat table from a website and I already have a function running so that when I type a team name into the website it returns a number. However, what I'm trying to do is have it so that when i type a team name in it won't return a number, but rather it's respective row on the table. The numbers that are currently called in the function are just placeholders for now. As you can see i tried to call a row at the end of the function using an ID I assigned to the Celtics row but what it returns is [object HTMLTableRowElement]. 
Any help is appreciated, Thanks!!

```
 <html>
<canvas id = 'gCanvas' width = '400' height = '600'></canvas>
<script>
var groceryItem = "";

window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('gCanvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressed, false);
};

function keyPressed(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != '13') {
        var letter = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(e.keyCode));
        groceryItem += letter;
        console.log(groceryItem);
    }

    if (e.keyCode == '13') {
        grocery();
        groceryItem = "";
    }

}

function grocery() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawBackground();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.font="40px Arial";

    switch (groceryItem) {
case 'CELTICS':
    ctx.fillText("1", 50, 50);
    break;
  case 'CAVALIERS':
  case 'CAVS':
    ctx.fillText('2', 50, 50);
    break;
  case 'WIZARDS':
    ctx.fillText('3', 50, 50);
    break;
  case 'RAPTORS':
    ctx.fillText('4', 50, 50);
    break;
  case 'HAWKS':
    ctx.fillText('5', 50, 50);
    break;
    case 'BUCKS':
    ctx.fillText('6', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'PACERS':
    ctx.fillText('7', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'HEAT':
    ctx.fillText('8', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'BULLS':
    ctx.fillText('9', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'PISTONS':
    ctx.fillText('10', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'HORNETS':
    ctx.fillText('11', 50, 50);
    break;
     case '76ERS':
    ctx.fillText('12', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'KNICKS':
    ctx.fillText('13', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'MAGIC':
    ctx.fillText('14', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'NETS':
    ctx.fillText('15', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'WARRIORS':
    ctx.fillText('16', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'SPURS':
    ctx.fillText(index('23'), 100, 100);
    break;
     case 'ROCKETS':
    ctx.fillText('18', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'JAZZ':
    ctx.fillText('19', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'CLIPPERS':
    ctx.fillText('20', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'THUNDER':
    ctx.fillText('21', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'GRIZZLIES':
    ctx.fillText('22', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'TRAILBLAZERS':
    ctx.fillText('23', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'NUGGETS':
    ctx.fillText('24', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'MAVERICKS':
    ctx.fillText('25', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'PELICANS':
    ctx.fillText('26', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'TIMBERWOLVES':
    ctx.fillText('27', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'KINGS':
    ctx.fillText('28', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'SUNS':
    ctx.fillText('29', 50, 50);
    break;
     case 'LAKERS':
    ctx.fillText('30', 50, 50);
    break;
  default:
    ctx.fillText('Invalid Team', 50, 50);
    break;

    }
}
function drawBackground() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

}
</script>

<div class="nba-stat-table">
  <div class="nba-stat-table__overflow" data-fixed="2" role="grid">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th sort="" cf="" data-field="TEAM_NAME" class="text sorted desc" ripple=""><br>TEAM</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" data-field="GP" data-rank="" data-dir="-1" ripple="">GP</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" data-field="W" data-rank="" data-dir="-1" ripple="">W</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" data-field="L" data-rank="" data-dir="-1" ripple="">L</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" data-field="W_PCT" data-rank="" data-dir="-1" ripple="" class="asc">WIN%</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" data-field="MIN" data-rank="" data-dir="-1" ripple="">MIN</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" data-field="EFG_PCT" data-rank="" data-dir="-1" ripple="">eFG%</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" data-field="FTA_RATE" data-rank="" data-dir="-1" ripple="">FTA<br>Rate</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" data-field="TM_TOV_PCT" data-rank="" data-dir="-1" ripple="">TOV%</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" data-field="OREB_PCT" data-rank="" data-dir="-1" ripple="">OREB%</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" data-field="OPP_EFG_PCT" data-rank="" data-dir="-1" ripple="">Opp<br>eFG%</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" data-field="OPP_FTA_RATE" data-rank="" data-dir="-1" ripple="">Opp<br>FTA&nbsp;Rate</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" data-field="OPP_TOV_PCT" data-rank="" data-dir="-1" ripple="">Opp<br>TOV%</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" data-field="OPP_OREB_PCT" data-rank="" data-dir="-1" ripple="">Opp<br>OREB%</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" hidden="" data-field="GP_RANK" ripple="">GP RANK</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" hidden="" data-field="W_RANK" ripple="">W RANK</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" hidden="" data-field="L_RANK" ripple="">L RANK</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" hidden="" data-field="W_PCT_RANK" ripple="">WIN% RANK</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" hidden="" data-field="MIN_RANK" ripple="">MIN RANK</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" hidden="" data-field="EFG_PCT_RANK" ripple="">eFG% RANK</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" hidden="" data-field="FTA_RATE_RANK" ripple="">FTA<br>Rate RANK</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" hidden="" data-field="TM_TOV_PCT_RANK" ripple="">TO<br>Ratio RANK</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" hidden="" data-field="OREB_PCT_RANK" ripple="">OREB% RANK</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" hidden="" data-field="OPP_EFG_PCT_RANK" ripple="">Opp<br>eFG% RANK</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" hidden="" data-field="OPP_FTA_RATE_RANK" ripple="">Opp<br>FTA&nbsp;Rate RANK</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" hidden="" data-field="OPP_TOV_PCT_RANK" ripple="">Opp<br>To&nbsp;Ratio RANK</th>
            <th sort="" cf="" hidden="" data-field="OPP_OREB_PCT_RANK" ripple="">Opp<br>OREB% RANK</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- ngRepeat: (i, row) in page track by row.$hash --><tr data-ng-repeat="(i, row) in page track by row.$hash" index="5" class="ng-scope">
            <td class="rank ng-binding"></td>
            <td class="team-name first sorted"><a href="/team/#!/1610612764/traditional/?" class="ng-binding">Washington Wizards</a></td>
            <td class="ng-binding">74</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">46</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">28</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">.622</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">3,587</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">52.7</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">0.255</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">14.0</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">24.0</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">52.1</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">0.284</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">15.4</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">24.5</td>
                  </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: (i, row) in page track by row.$hash --><tr data-ng-repeat="(i, row) in page track by row.$hash" index="3" class="ng-scope" id=1>
            <td class="rank ng-binding"></td>
            <td class="team-name first sorted"><a href="/team/#!/1610612738/traditional/?" class="ng-binding">Boston Celtics</a></td>
            <td class="ng-binding">74</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">48</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">26</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">.649</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">3,567</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">52.4</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">0.269</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">13.4</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">21.3</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">50.4</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">0.289</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">14.1</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">25.0</td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: (i, row) in page track by row.$hash --><tr data-ng-repeat="(i, row) in page track by row.$hash" index="12" class="ng-scope">
            <td class="rank ng-binding"></td>
            <td class="team-name first sorted"><a href="/team/#!/1610612737/traditional/?" class="ng-binding">Atlanta Hawks</a></td>
            <td class="ng-binding">74</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">38</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">36</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">.514</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">3,587</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">50.3</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">0.297</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">15.6</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">23.6</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">50.8</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">0.233</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">15.3</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">24.1</td>
          </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: (i, row) in page track by row.$hash -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div> <!-- .stat-table__overflow -->
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('1')
document.write(document.getElementById('1'))
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: No comments on the mammoth switch statement, but I’m wondering about the `ngRepeat`. Your best bet is (a) to generate a unique `id` for each row, (b) use an expression like `document.querySelector(…)` to fetch the row by its `id`, (c) read the results from the fetched row.

Comment: Thanks Manngo, the thing is I already tried that by giving the Celtics row the ID of 1, and then having it read it, but it came out as [object HTMLTableRowElement] and not as the actual table row which is what im trying to get

Comment: You’re on the way. The object is a DOM element, and you will need to iterate through it. I’ll give an example of the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**

[<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/qHnxVleipnCKefAzQl70/)

---

**UPDATE 1**

✎ in Snippet's comments denotes the update.

---

Used the [`.map()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) method to iterate through each row (team), cell (stat column), and cell content (stat), Details are commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET 1**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nba-stat-table">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th data-field="TEAM_NAME" class="text sorted desc"><br>TEAM</th>
          <th data-field="GP">GP</th>
          <th data-field="W">W</th>
          <th data-field="L">L</th>
          <th data-field="W_PCT" class="asc">WIN%</th>
          <th data-field="MIN">MIN</th>
          <th data-field="EFG_PCT">eFG%</th>
          <th data-field="FTA_RATE">FTA<br>Rate</th>
          <th data-field="TM_TOV_PCT">TOV%</th>
          <th data-field="OREB_PCT">OREB%</th>
          <th data-field="OPP_EFG_PCT">Opp<br>eFG%</th>
          <th data-field="OPP_FTA_RATE">Opp<br>FTA&nbsp;Rate</th>
          <th data-field="OPP_TOV_PCT">Opp<br>TOV%</th>
          <th data-field="OPP_OREB_PCT">Opp<br>OREB%</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="rank"></td>
          <td class="team-name first sorted">
            <a href="http://stats.nba.com/team/#!/1610612764/traditional/?">Washington Wizards</a>
          </td>
          <td>74</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>.622</td>
          <td>3,587</td>
          <td>52.7</td>
          <td>0.255</td>
          <td>14.0</td>
          <td>24.0</td>
          <td>52.1</td>
          <td>0.284</td>
          <td>15.4</td>
          <td>24.5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="rank"></td>
          <td class="team-name first sorted">
            <a href="http://stats.nba.com/team/#!/1610612738/traditional/?">Boston Celtics</a>
          </td>
          <td>74</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>.649</td>
          <td>3,567</td>
          <td>52.4</td>
          <td>0.269</td>
          <td>13.4</td>
          <td>21.3</td>
          <td>50.4</td>
          <td>0.289</td>
          <td>14.1</td>
          <td>25.0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="rank"></td>
          <td class="team-name first sorted">
            <a href="http://stats.nba.com/team/#!/1610612737/traditional/?">Atlanta Hawks</a>
          </td>
          <td>74</td>
          <td>38</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>.514</td>
          <td>3,587</td>
          <td>50.3</td>
          <td>0.297</td>
          <td>15.6</td>
          <td>23.6</td>
          <td>50.8</td>
          <td>0.233</td>
          <td>15.3</td>
          <td>24.1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script>
    // Reference the table ✎
    var T = document.querySelector('table');

    /* Collect the cells from the 1st row of T
    || then convert HTMLCollection into an array ✎
    */
    var cols = Array.from(T.rows[0].cells);

    /* map() passing cols array 
    || returns the array of header titles ✎
    */
    var cats = cols.map(function(th, idx) {
      return th.textContent;
    });


    /* Collect all <tr> in <tbody> in a NodeList
    || Convert NodeList into an array
    */
    var rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr'));

    // Use the .map() method to...
    rows.map(function(tr, idx) {

      /* ...iterate through each <tr>
      || and collect it's <td> to a HTMLCollection
      || then convert it to an array
      */
      var cells = Array.from(tr.children);

      // Use the .map() method to...
      cells.map(function(td, idx) {

        // ...get the text from each <td>
        var stat = td.textContent;

        /* Log results ✎
        || The first part is a iteration
        || of the cats array which consists
        || of the text of each category
        || title in the column headers (<th>)
        */
        console.log(cats[idx] + ': ' + stat);

        // return results as a new array of stats
        return stat;
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it finally brings up the actual stats and that's a big step. The only issue now is that it brings up all the stats, for all the teams, with no formatting whatsoever, how can i fix that? Like so (Washington Wizards744628.6223,58752.70.25514.024.052.10.28415.424.5Utah Jazz744529.6083,56752.20.29114.623.349.20.25612.921.0Toronto Raptors744529.6083,57251.60.29612.924.950.80.29015.023.5)

Comment: @Gferragamo FYI, in code provided, table and data are not complete. But that is expected and appreciated, since the full data and table from the site would be too much to post.

Comment: Thank you Zer00ne, that made it better but what I'm trying to do is a little more complicated. You've already helped me three times so I don't wan't to be a bother. If you have time however, comment back and i'll explain quickly what it is i'm trying to do. Thanks again

Comment: @Gferragamo I can't guarantee that'll I'll have enough time to figure it out, but go ahead and explain, sir. I can try after work or whatever.

Comment: The switch statement at the top has a list of teams, and right now I can enter the site, search the team name, and have it print to the canvas whatever i put into the switch. I want to make it so that i can call one row of data (for a respective team) after i have typed the team name into the site (If you look i currently have numbers in the switch for what to print, but ideally it would be the row of stats.) Also, for the previous data print that you showed me, the first code would work better (without the letters) because I could just have a preset table, they just need to be spaced out.  TY

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is

- generate a unique id for each row
- use an expression like document.querySelector(…) to fetch the row by its id
- read the results from the fetched row

You can read the content of a row by iterating through the data cells.

The function `document.querySelectorAll()` will return a collection of elements which match a CSS-type pattern. We can then use a `for` loop to get the cell contents. I have used `textContent`, but if you need to support Legacy Browsers, you might use `innerHTML`.

```
var row=document.querySelectorAll('tr#id-1>td');
var data=[];
for(var i=0;i<row.length;i++) data.push(row[i].textContent);
```

The `data` array will now have your content, and you can process that as you like.